# How to uniquely identify a slack user across all the teams they're in

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I am aware a slack user's user id is not globally unique but that it can be combined with their team id to be globally unique. However, I want to be able to identify people across all the teams they are in. Is the only way to achieve this by storing all their team id's or is there a way to get one id that can uniquely identify a user within my app?

I have seen something about using Sign In With Slack to get an identity token. Would this token work in identifying a single user across all the teams that they are in?

Comment: In which api do they provide the identity token , I have never recieved in this one https://api.slack.com/docs/sign-in-with-slack, nor in this one https://api.slack.com/methods/users.identity

Comment: @bhucho in the second link it says "After your Slack app is awarded an identity token through Sign in with Slack, use this method to retrieve a user's identity." so I assumed this meant you can use it to identify a user

Comment: they do have told that `User IDs are not guaranteed to be globally unique across all Slack users. The combination of user ID and team ID, on the other hand, is guaranteed to be globally unique.` , so I don't think though you can contact them, still I don't think they will provide that as it is associated uniquely with them